# pip install git+http:// with a private git repository

Tags: python, git, .htaccess, pip, apache2

I am running an apache2 server on my local NAS and have the git module enabled. There is little in the way of security, but I did put an .htaccess on the git repository directory. This requires a username/password and probably would only keep the honest folks out.

I recently dipped my toe in Python and was curious if I would be able to install a pip module from my git server:

```
pip install git+http://192.168.1.70/git/openai-whisper@sandbox
```

but I was getting the following error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'http://192.168.1.70/git/openau-whisper': No such file or directory
```

Now, I did find a work around: If I first clone the repo to my local machine first and use git credential manager to remember the username/password, then I install the pip module without error.

Is there a way to perform "pip install git+" and be prompted for a username/passsword to validate through an .htaccess? I prefer to not use the git credential manager and just type the user/pass each time.

Thank you!

Comment: "could not read Username for ... : No such file or directory" check your authentication configuration.  Probably the wrong file is specified in your config and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Before using git credential manager, it did prompt for user/pass. The config on my nas is correct as when I just use "git" to clone repositories it prompts every time.  When I use "pip install git+" it does not prompt